# React error in render/flush: RangeError in flush RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, stack, max, size

I've been in the process of rewriting an old AngularJS app in React (actually it's using preact, chosen by the developer who started this project initially).

This app handles large deeply nested objects that get be displayed via Material UI accordions and tables. The data is more WIDE than deep, but at any rate, React has trouble rendering it all without this RangeError.

I've been dancing with this issue for a while now and have avoided it by strategically managing accordions and not rendering data for accordions that are not open.

I've commonly seen this reported as a recursion issue, and I've carefully reviewed the ode to confirm there is no recursion involved. Plenty of iteration, but no recursion.

Please note the stack trace, it's hitting this in the flush() function, which is **not in our application code**, but in the Chrome debugger VM. I've set breakpoints and it appears to be something related to DOM operations as the objects being flushed are React elements. Here's a code snippet from the point where this error is hit:

```
   function flush(commit) {
      const {
        rootId,
        unmountIds,
        operations,
        strings,
        stats
      } = commit;
      if (unmountIds.length === 0 && operations.length === 0) return;
      const msg = [rootId, ...flushTable(strings)];
      if (unmountIds.length > 0) {
        msg.push(MsgTypes.REMOVE_VNODE, unmountIds.length, ...unmountIds);
      }
      msg.push(...operations);  <--- error occurs here when operations.length too long
```

And the stack trace logged when error occurs:

```
VM12639:1240 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at flush (<anonymous>:1240:8)
    at Object.onCommit (<anonymous>:3409:19)
    at o._commit.o.__c (<anonymous>:3678:15)
    at QRet.Y.options.__c (index.js:76:17)
    at Y (index.js:265:23)
    at component.js:141:3
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at m (component.js:220:9)
```

The error is occurring if operations is too large. Normally it will be anywhere from a dozen or so in length up to maybe 3000, depending on what's going on, but when I try to load our page displaying the wide/deep nested object this number is more like 150000, which apparently is choking the spread operator.

My sense is that this type of app is a challenge for React. I cannot think of another example of a React app that displays data the way we do with this. If anyone here has experience with this sort of dataset and can offer suggestions as to how to make this work, please share.

My guess is I'm going to need to somehow break this object up into smaller chunks that represent smaller updates, but I'm posting here in case there's something I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

It looks similar to [this open issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22293) on the React repo, only it happens in a different place (also in dev tools). Might be worth reporting your issue there too. So probably React is otherwise "fine" rendering this amount of elements, though you'll inevitably get slow performance.

### Likely the app is just displaying too much data, or doing it inefficiently.

> but when I try to load our page displaying the wide/deep nested object this number is more like 150000, ...

150000 DOM operations is a really high amount. Either your app really does display a whole lot of elements, or the old AngularJS app had too many wrapper elements and these were preserved. Since you mention it concerns data tables, it's probably the first reason. In any case complex applications always need some platform specific optimization.

If you can give an idea about the **intended use case**, or even better, share (parts of) the **code**, that would help others to give more targeted advice. Are the 150k operations close to what would happen in real world usage, or is it just a very inflated number for stress testing? Do you see any other performance regressions, compared to the Angular app, with very complex objects? How many tables are on the screen at a time?

A few hundreds of visible elements on the screen already gets quite cramped. So where would all these extra operations coming from? Either you're loading a super long page of which a user can only see a few percent at the same time, or the HTML structure is unnecessarily deeply nested.

### Suggested performance improvements

I wouldn't say React isn't suitable for really large amounts of data, but you do need to watch out for some things yourself. React is only your vehicle to apply changes to the DOM. Putting a large amount of elements in the DOM is always going to lead to decreased performance, and is something you usually want to avoid.

In this case you could consider whether it's necessary to display all the table's data, which is probably the bulk of the operations. Using **pagination** would resolve the problem, and might even make it more user friendly.

If that's not an option, you maybe can use a library like `react-lazyload` to show/hide the items as they enter/exit the visible part of the table. To achieve this, use their [`unmountIfInvisible` prop](https://github.com/twobin/react-lazyload#unmountifinvisible). You can then replace a complex data row with a single element that has the same height. The last is important to preserve the scroll height.

```
  <LazyLoad 
    height={100} 
    offset={100}
    unmountIfInvisible
    placeholder={<tr height={100}/>}
  >
    <MyComplexDataRow /> 
  </LazyLoad>
```

This way your data table never consists of much more complex elements than can be seen in the viewport. You probably need to tune the offset a bit so that it's always ready in time as it's benig scrolled.

Comment: Thanks much for the detailed response. The nature of this data object/application is that we cannot use pagination. The approach I'm experimenting with currently is to flatten the object into an array and track the depth, and simulate nested content using CSS. I'll see how this flies. Problem is I have some limitations to what I can try because the user base expects everything to behave/look like the legacy AngularJS app.